# Running an application with TomEE Maven plugin gives me "Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete"

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee, tomee-8

The following error is given when I try to deploy a simple app (the default one that IntelliJ provides when you create a new Java EE Web App project):

```
PS C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5> mvn clean; mvn package; mvn tomee:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.so:myApp >----------------------------
[INFO] Building myApp 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.913 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-08T01:03:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.so:myApp >----------------------------
[INFO] Building myApp 1.0                                                      
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ myApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.3.0:war (default-war) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [myApp] in [C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\myApp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\myApp.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.402 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-08T01:03:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.so:myApp >----------------------------
[INFO] Building myApp 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomee-maven-plugin:8.0.7:run (default-cli) @ myApp ---
[INFO] TomEE was unzipped in 'C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\apache-tomee'
[INFO] Removed not mandatory default webapps
[INFO] Installed 'C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\myApp.war' in C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\apache-tomee\webapps\myApp.war
[INFO] TomEE will run in development mode
[INFO] Running 'org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.run'. Configured TomEE in plugin is localhost:8080 (plugin shutdown port is 8005 and https port is null)
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.331 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.45
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.332 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server built:          Mar 30 2021 10:29:04 UTC
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.332 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version number: 9.0.45.0
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.332 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Name:               Windows 10
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.332 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Version:            10.0
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.333 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Architecture:          amd64
08-Feb-2022 01:03:57.333 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16


//Omitted because of stackoverflow message length limits


08-Feb-2022 01:04:00.592 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\apache-tomee\webapps\myApp
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.012 INFO [main] null.openjpa.Enhance You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, which might increase class load times significantly.
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.066 INFO [main] null.openjpa.Runtime OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.083 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate PersistenceUnit(name=default, provider=org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl) - provider time 438ms
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.145 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initSingleton Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@6dee4f1b
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.224 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.ManagedSecurityService.<init> Some Principal APIs could not be loaded: org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken out of org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken not found
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.265 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.272 INFO [main] org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.867 INFO [main] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints All injection points were validated successfully.
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.886 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 620 ms.
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.897 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\Anton\IdeaProjects\demo5\target\apache-tomee\webapps\myApp)
08-Feb-2022 01:04:01.904 SEVERE [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.InternalError: LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,i
nt,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @cb644e
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory$Unsafe.getClassLoaderDefineClassMethod(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:845)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory$Unsafe.defineClass(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:828)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.eagerInitOfLocalBeanProxies(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1598)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1344)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5077)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:836)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDom
ain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @cb644e
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory$Unsafe.getClassLoaderDefineClassMethod(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:845)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory$Unsafe.defineClass(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:828)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.eagerInitOfLocalBeanProxies(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1598)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1344)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5077)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

                at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:145)
                at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:152)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.eagerInitOfLocalBeanProxies(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1598)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1344)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5077)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
                ... 28 more
08-Feb-2022 01:04:02.027 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Feb-2022 01:04:02.036 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in [2983] milliseconds
```

If I try to manually deploy the same .war file in my personal TomEE installation using `startup.bat` this error does not occur.

I have tried both TomEE 8.0.7 and 8.0.8; this is the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.so</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>myApp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeClassifier>webprofile</tomeeClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What can possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Java 16 (as shown in the log file) with Maven. In this case, you should use TomEE in version 8.0.9 as this release contains important fixes regarding illegal reflective access (due to the use of Unsafe for proxy creation) in higher versions of Java. You find some details in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-3795

It looks like you are using a lower Java version for running your standalone TomEE deployment, which works as it isn't as restrictive as newer Java versions.

Side Note: Java 16 is end-of-life and you should better switch to Java 17.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Indeed both switching to 8.0.9 and sticking with 8.0.8 (but using Java 11) did the trick. The app was actually supposed to run on Java 11, but the path variable once again mocked me.